# ActiveX Error when pasting from excel to powerpoint via vba

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am working on a macro that builds a briefing template based on data entered into excel

Error I am receiving:
ActiveX component can't create object or return reference to this object (Error 429)

Since their are various objets that need to be created on several slides i wrote a subroutine that can be reused for each object based on some settings set within the excel file

This is the subroutine that runs

Its erring out on the paste function itself, hovering over the variables within that line gives me the correct values required. I have tested it on its own and it works fine with the values its receiving. I also check to ensure that the values were copied from excel and they were.

I am kin dof at a loss on this one.

```
Private Sub AddShape(vSummary As Boolean, vSheet As String, vRange As String, vFirstSlide As Integer, vLastSlide As Integer, vTop As Double, vLeft As Double)
Dim Sld As Integer
'Copy specified cells
    WB.Sheets(vSheet).Range(vRange).Copy
'Paste to first required slide for the specified cell group
    ActivePresentation.Slides(vFirstSlide).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
'Set the specified top position
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = (vTop * vDPI)
'Center everything before we begin
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
'Determine if Left position needs set'
    If vLeft Then
       ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = (vLeft * vDPI)
    End If
'If contents is a Summary
    If vSummary Then
'While we still have it selected
        With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue  'Lock Aspect Ratio
            .Width = (10 * vDPI)        'Reszie to fit slide'
            .Ungroup                    'Ungroup to make it easier to edit manually'
        End With
    Else
        'Ungroup to make it easier to edit manually then copy it to paste it to all the required slides
        ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup.Copy
        'We pasted one already so we need to set the new first slide to the second in the series of slides to recieve the current content
        vFirstSlide = vFirstSlide + 1
        'For the specified remaineder of the slides we paste the contents we just copied.
        'NOTE: this only works if the contents are to be placed on a concurrent set of slides. this will break if the content you are adding requires random placements in the templates
        For Sld = vFirstSlide To vLastSlide
            ActivePresentation.Slides(Sld).Shapes.Paste
        Next Sld
    End If
End Sub
```

I am calling from the following subroutine

```
Sub BuildTemplate()

'Set Global Variables
Set WB = Workbooks("tool.xlsm")             'Set this to the name of the excel file
Set Settings = WB.Sheets("SETTINGS")        'Set this to the name of the settings tab
Set Build = WB.Sheets("BUILD")              'Set this to the name of the build tab
Set Entry = WB.Sheets("ENTRY")              'Set this to the name of the entry tab

    vDPI = Settings.Cells(2, "B").Value

'Adjust column sizes
    Build.Columns(2).AutoFit
    Build.Columns(4).AutoFit
    Build.Columns(6).AutoFit
    Build.Columns(8).AutoFit

'Create Template Files
MoveFiles
'Open newly created Template File
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPT.Visible = True
    PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:=vNewPrimaryTemplatePath
'Add Title Block
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("E2")), CInt(Settings.Range("E3")), CInt(Settings.Range("E4")), CDbl(Settings.Range("E5")), CDbl(Settings.Range("E6")))

'Add Delivery Block
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("E9")), CInt(Settings.Range("E10")), CInt(Settings.Range("E11")), CDbl(Settings.Range("E12")), CDbl(Settings.Range("E13")))

'Add Address Block
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("E16")), CInt(Settings.Range("E17")), CInt(Settings.Range("E18")), CDbl(Settings.Range("E19")), CDbl(Settings.Range("E20")))

'Add Items
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H2")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H12")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H10")))
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H3")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H13")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H10")))
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H4")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H14")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H10")))
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H5")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H15")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H10")))
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H6")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H12")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H11")))
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H7")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H13")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H11")))
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H8")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H14")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H11")))
Call AddShape(False, "BUILD", CStr(Settings.Range("H9")), CInt(Settings.Range("H16")), CInt(Settings.Range("H17")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H15")), CDbl(Settings.Range("H11")))

'Add Summaries
    AddSummary

'Save & Close
    ActivePresentation.SaveAs Filename:=vNewPrimaryTemplatePath, FileFormat:=ppSaveAsDefault
    ActivePresentation.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried pasting grouped and then ungrouping?

Comment: Is it possible that the context of the Paste is what's causing the problem - meaning you're copying a ShapeRange object but trying to paste a Shape object.  Are they definitely fungible?

Comment: I am pasting as a group initially which is where the error is happening. As for the Shape object as I stated above it works fine on its own and ShapeRange is not an object of Slides but rather of Selection

Comment: Go into your debugger and use the locals windows to work out which of these is not an object: `ActivePresentation.`, `ActivePresentation.Slides(Sld)`, `ActivePresentation.Slides(Sld).Shapes` I guess one of those is not an object and that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it all out and get it working fine.

It was a scope issue the ActivePresentation inside the subprocedue did not have access to the powerpoint application. Making the PPT object global and using that infront of the Active presentation enabled it to work.

Their were some object issues as well as ElectricLlama has pointed out. here is the final rewrite of the subroutine

```
Private Sub AddShape(vSummary As Boolean, vSheet As String, vRange As String, Optional vFirstSlide As Integer, Optional vLastSlide As Integer, Optional vTop As Double, Optional vLeft As Variant = "Centered")
Dim Sld As Integer
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oShape As Object

'Copy specified cells
    WB.Sheets(vSheet).Range(vRange).Copy
'Paste to first required slide for the specified cell group
Set oSlide = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(vFirstSlide)
Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
'Center everything before we begin
    oShape.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    oShape.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
'Set the specified top position
    oShape.Top = (vTop * vDPI)
'Determine if Left position needs set'
    If vLeft = "Centered" Then
        oShape.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    Else
        oShape.Left = (vLeft * vDPI)
    End If
'If contents is a Summary
    If vSummary Then
'While we still have it selected
        With oShape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue  'Lock Aspect Ratio
            .Width = (10 * vDPI)        'Reszie to fit slide'
            .Ungroup                    'Ungroup to make it easier to edit manually'
        End With
    Else
        'Ungroup to make it easier to edit manually then copy it to paste it to all the required slides
        oShape.Ungroup.Copy
        'We pasted one already so we need to set the new first slide to the second in the series of slides to recieve the current content
        vFirstSlide = vFirstSlide + 1
        'For the specified remaineder of the slides we paste the contents we just copied.
        'NOTE: this only works if the contents are to be placed on a concurrent set of slides. this will break if the content you are adding requires random placements in the templates
        For Sld = vFirstSlide To vLastSlide
            PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(Sld).Shapes.Paste
        Next Sld
    End If

End Sub
```